# Pressing F5 in Visual Studio opens selected file

Tags: visual-studio

I have been a bit hesitant to post this as a question as I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

When I press F5 in Visual Studio 2012 it builds my web app and launches in IE with whatever file is currently selected file in the solution explorer. So if I've got a html file selected I'll get that html page displayed, or if I've got an aspx file selected then it will try to open that particular page.

My expected behaviour when I press F5 is that it will *run the application* not the individual files I may happen to be working on. So when I press F5 I want it to build and launch my web app which *is* set as the startup project BTW.

So either I need to have my expectations adjusted or I'm being totally thick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand -- are you expecting visual studio to run some sort of index/login/etc. page instead of what you're currently looking at?

If so:

1. right click the project
2. select properties
3. select  web
4. set the specific page